# Not getting user.username from telegram login

Tags: javascript, telegram

```
<script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?11" data-telegram-login="Xyz007bot" data-size="large" data-onauth="onTelegramAuth(user)" data-request-access="write"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onTelegramAuth(user) {
    alert('Logged in as ' + user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name + ' (' + user.id + (user.username ? ', @' + user.username : '') + ')');
  }
</script>
```

how do i get username here?
In this above code i added this javascript code that is generated by telegram login widget but this is not doing well.

Comment: what issue u r facing?

Comment: Actually i want to login users using telegram api, but the above code is not providing username, it is printing first name, last name is and even hash but not the username